# FlexLayout No Longer Wraps After Upgrading Visual Studio to 17.4.0 Preview 1.0

Tags: maui

I have MAUI app that is complete, that was working as expected.  I just upgraded Visual Studio 2022 from 17.3.0 Preview 3.0 to 17.4.0 Preview 1.0.  Now the FlexLayout view I'm using is no longer wrapping content.

Here is the tag for my FlexLayout control:

```
<FlexLayout                    
   x:Name="BadgesView" 
   Wrap="Wrap"
   Margin="{x:Static thepage:MyStuffPageCustom.FLEX_MARGIN}"
   AlignContent="Stretch"
   JustifyContent="SpaceBetween">
</FlexLayout>
```

I'm at a complete loss for what to do now.  It is not wrapping on my emulated Android and iOS devices, as well as my physical iOS device; basically on nothing - all devices where it was working previously.  How are we supposed to troubleshoot or fix this one?

UPDATE

I recreated this in a new MAUI project.  Here's the full code.

**XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAppWrap.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>

        <Grid 
            x:Name="BadgesGrid"
            RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" 
            ColumnDefinitions="*">

            <Border 
                Grid.Row="0" 
                Grid.Column="0"
                Stroke="{StaticResource FriendCard}" 
                StrokeThickness="3"
                Margin="3,5,3,10">

            <Border.StrokeShape>
                <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5" />
            </Border.StrokeShape>
                
            <VerticalStackLayout
                Spacing="25"
                Padding="30,0"
                VerticalOptions="Center">

                <FlexLayout                    
                    x:Name="BadgesView" 
                    Wrap="Wrap"
                    Margin="10,0,10,0"
                    AlignContent="Stretch"
                    JustifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                </FlexLayout>

                <HorizontalStackLayout 
                    x:Name="NextBadgeHorzLayout"
                    Margin="0,10,0,0">

                    <Label 
                        Text="NEXT BADGE:" 
                        FontSize="Medium"
                        FontAttributes="Bold" 
                        Margin="10,0,0,4"
                        TextColor="Orange" />

                    <Label 
                        x:Name="NextBadgeLevelLabel"
                        Margin="3,-3,0,0" FontSize="Small"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                        Text="MY NEXT BADGE"
                        Style="{StaticResource MetricsLabel}" />

                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                
            </VerticalStackLayout>
                
            </Border>

        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);

        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            VerticalStackLayout vsl = new VerticalStackLayout();

            Border bord = new Border()
            {
                Stroke = Color.FromArgb("#e6b800"),
                StrokeThickness = 3,
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#ffcc00"),
                HeightRequest = 48,
                WidthRequest = 48,
                StrokeShape = new Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shapes.RoundRectangle
                {
                    CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(50)
                }
            };

            Image im = new Image()
            {
                Source = ImageSource.FromFile($"circle_badge1.png"),
                HeightRequest = 32,
                WidthRequest = 32,
                Margin = new Thickness(5), 
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill
            };

            bord.Content = im;

            Label l = new Label()
            {
                Text = $"MY TEST {i}",
                FontSize = 10,
                TextColor = Color.FromArgb("#e67e00"),
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, 
                Padding = new Thickness(3)
            };

            vsl.Add(bord); 
            vsl.Add(l);

            BadgesView.Add(vsl);
        }
    }
```

Here's the circle badge in case you want to see or use it:

[image]

Here's how it actually renders now that VS has been upgraded to 17.4:

[image]

Here's how this kind of thing looks on the previous version, from an iPhone emulator:

[image]

Again, no code changes - just upgraded to 17.4 and world imploded.

Comment: Do you mean when you set the `Wrap="Wrap"`, the result is same as the `Wrap="NoWrap"` ? I have done a sample with the visual studio 17.3.0 preview 6.0, it worked well.

Comment: Yes, everything was working fine until I upgraded.  Now that I've upgraded, it doesn't wrap.  I've tried all three options for the Wrap parameter and it makes no difference, it is rendered exactly the same for each.

Comment: Also, please note - I am not in the 17.3.0 builds anymore; I just upgraded to 17.4.0 Preview 1.0.

Comment: It seems a bug in the 17.4.0 preview 1.0. You can report it on the github.

Comment: I can confirm the same issue. I spent an hour rolling back code thinking I broke something, but then realized I just upgraded to 17.4.0 preview 1.0 earlier today (from I think 17.3.0 preview 5)

Comment: Steve - FWIW, I have "kind of a work around"...i.e. I can get it to look mostly like a FlexLayout but it's not perfect.  And it may not work for your scenario.  But just in case...I used a CollectionView and configured it to use a GridItemsLayout with a vertical orientation that spanned 4 items.  I just stuck this below the CollectionView tag:  <CollectionView.ItemsLayout><GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="4"/>/CollectionView.ItemsLayout>      Don't know if it will help, but just in case.

Comment: Thanks for work-around. That works for me until it is fixed. I'm still early on in my project, so it's not a huge deal for me, but I need something to at least make my UI work for testing.